# Option to create a new Flutter project is missing after upgrade of Android Studio (3.4) and Flutter Plugin (38.2.1)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-plugin

After upgrading Android Studio to (3.4) and my Flutter Plugin to (38.2.1), the option to create a new project is missing from the Android Studio startup screen. I've tried the following things detailed below. Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

1. Flutter Doctor Summary

   ```
   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132, locale en-US)
       • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 
       • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (4 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
       • Engine revision fee001c93f
       • Dart version 2.4.0

   [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
       • Android SDK 
       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
       • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
       • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
       • All Android licenses accepted.

   [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.2.1)
       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
       • Xcode 10.2.1, Build version 10E1001
       • CocoaPods version 1.6.1

   [✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
       • ios-deploy 1.9.4

   [✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
       • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
       • Flutter plugin version 38.2.1
       • Dart plugin version 183.6270
       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

   [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
       • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
       • Flutter plugin version 34.0.4
       • Dart plugin version 191.6183.88

   [✓] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
       • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
       • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

   [✓] Connected device (1 available)
       • iPhone Xʀ • D5A5B892-EA4E-4632-8562-D5A55B823E71 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2 (simulator)

   • No issues found!
   ```
2. In Android Studio, verified that Android Studio->Plugins shows Flutter and Dart plugins are enabled.
3. In Android Studio, verified that Android Studio->Preferences->Languages & Frameworks shows Flutter and Dart are supported.
4. After upgrade, exited Android Studio and restarted MAC.
5. As a work around, I'm creating a new project from the command line, and then editing and running the project from Android Studio.

Comment: Try updating your flutter plugin to the latest version `38.2.4`. And make sure to update the `dart` plugin too.

Comment: Thanks, will try it.